# How to implement Google Directions API in android using Libraries?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I have searched internet for almost 10 hours for this thing but no luck...A clean and clear explanation on how to use google directions api in google maps v2 would really be helpful....

I have gone through the whole long process though but I want to use a library because I am too lazy to implement that huge code with that of mine....

I had successfully implemented this library from [polok](https://github.com/polok/RouteDrawer).

But as you can see in the screenshot that directions are not precise and polylines are moving off-road after a few turns....

I also found this library by [tyczj](https://github.com/tyczj/MapNavigator).

But with no implementation....

An example using this library would be very helpful or any other way to implement google direcions API.....

Here is a snippet of my MapActivity:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available
    double latitude, longitude;
    Bundle extras;
    String add;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    LatLng position;

    private Location mLastLocation;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean mInProgress;


    // boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    // Location updates intervals in sec
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL)
                .setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !mInProgress) {
            mInProgress = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }


        add = extras.getString("address");

        geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(add,1);

            if(addresses.size()>0){

                latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
                longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        position = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(add));

        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(), 12F);

        mMap.animateCamera(cu);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        mInProgress = false;
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        displayLocation();


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;

        displayLocation();


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    private LatLng displayLocation() {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double myLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double myLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.current))
                    .title("Me"));

            return new LatLng(myLatitude,myLongitude);

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you all for replying.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself.....

Sorry it was not a good question though but then too if anyone else is looking for similar answer here is one:

I found [this](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android) library along with the implementation, check this one out...simple to implement with precise routing...